# call javascript function when error message exists

Tags: javascript, error-messages

I have a scenario where I have to produce a sound when a specific error message exists out of many error messages from the apex class.

I built a JavaScript function for the sound.

```
    <audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>

       <apex:pagemessages>

    <apex:actionsupport event = 'onchange' onsubmit = 'PlaySound()' />



    </apex:pagemessages>

​    <script>

    function PlaySound() {

          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");

          sound.play()

      }

    </script>
```

But how do I call "`PlaySound()`" when there is an error message.
I tried using actionsupport for this, but it didn't work.
I'm not sure whether actionsupport executes on error message on page or not.

How do I get to call the function when error exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a snippet which is executed only when there are messages on the page of a given severity. As long as this `apex:outputPanel` is re-rendered, so it has the most up-to-date values from the controller, you should get a sound played when an `ApexPages.Message` is on the page with the given severity.

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <script>
        function PlaySound() {
            console.log('Sound played!');
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ErrorMessagesOnPage}" id="soundNotice">
            <script>
                (function() {
                    PlaySound();
                })();
            </script>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:commandButton action="{!RefreshPage}" value="Refresh Page" />

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController {

    public TestController() {}

    public Boolean ErrorMessagesOnPage {
        get {
            return ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR);
        }
    }

    public PageReference RefreshPage() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Something went wrong!'));

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it and it's throwing a javascript error " Uncaught ReferenceError: PlaySound is not defined" from chrome browser debug console

Comment: I've added a more complete example. As long as your page is set up similarly, you shouldn't have any issues.